# Adding point-and-click navigation to a three.js project where OrbitControls is enabled

Tags: javascript, three.js, gsap, orbitcontrols

I am making a [navigation test](https://github.com/mqbaka02/threeJS_navigation_test) in three.js with a point-and-click navigation functionality.

The point-and-click mechanic is really simple : a raycaster determines the point in the plane where the user clicked and I move the camera there with `gsap`:

```js
const move_cam = () => {
    const new_pos = { ...marker.position };
    gsap.to(camera.position, {
      duration: 2,
      x: new_pos.x,
      z: new_pos.z,

      onComplete: () => {
      }
    });
  };
```

The problem with this is that, when used along with OrbitControls, the camera moves while always pointing to the same place :
[image: camera is moving but stays focused on one point]

The reason is that OrbitControls gives a target to the camera to keep looking at, allowing it to "orbit".

My first attempt was just to disable OrbitControls during the camera movement with `controls.enabled= false` and reenabling it after the fact with the callback function `onComplete()` of `gsap` but it doesn't work since `controls.enabled= false` only disables the interaction with the user but it doesn't keep the camera from looking at its target.

I also thought about preventing OrbitControls to affect the camera during the movement by adding a condition to the animation loop :

```
if (!camera_is_moving) {
controls.update();
}
```

But the camera goes back to looking at the target as soon as the animation is finished.

As a last ressort, I decided to store the distance of the camera to its target in an variable called `offset` and then using that offset to define a new target at the end of the animation. And the `move_cam()` function ended up like this :

```js
const move_cam = () => {
    camera_is_moving = true;
    const offset = {
      x: controls.target.x - camera.position.x,
      y: controls.target.y - camera.position.y,
      z: controls.target.z - camera.position.z,
    };

    const new_pos = { ...marker.position };
    new_pos.y = CAMERA_HEIGHT;
    
    gsap.to(camera.position, {
      duration: 2,
      x: new_pos.x,
      y: new_pos.y,
      z: new_pos.z,

      onComplete: () => {
        controls.target.x = offset.x + camera.position.x;
        // controls.target.y= offset.x + camera.position.y;
        controls.target.z = offset.x + camera.position.z;

        offset.x = controls.target.x - camera.position.x;
        offset.y = controls.target.y - camera.position.y;
        offset.z = controls.target.z - camera.position.z;
        camera_is_moving = false;
      }

    });
  };
```

I was sure it would work and I kind of did but the camera kind of twitches at the end of the animation as if the new target I assigned was not quite the correct one :

[image: Camera twitches at the end of animation]

If you look closely at the gif, right at the end of the animation, the camera stutters a bit. Sometimes it's very significant and sometimes it's just a small movement.

I don't know what's causing this, my objective is that the camera's rotation stays the same as before the animation so I thought that if I offset the camera's target by the same amount as the camera itself, it would work but apparently, it didn't.

Can anyone help me with this?

I uploaded the project in this [Github repo](https://github.com/mqbaka02/threeJS_navigation_test) if you want to try and see what I mean.
The full js file is [here](https://github.com/mqbaka02/threeJS_navigation_test/blob/checker/src/script.js).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by animating the camera target separately with gsap instead of setting its value in the `onComplete()` callback so the `move_cam()` function ended up like this :

```js
const move_cam = () => {
    camera_is_moving = true;
    controls.enabled = false;
    const offset = {
      x: controls.target.x - camera.position.x,
      y: controls.target.y - camera.position.y,
      z: controls.target.z - camera.position.z,
    };
    const new_pos = { ...marker.position };
    new_pos.y = camera.position.y;

    gsap.to(this.camera.position, {
      duration: this.camera_travel_duration,
      x: new_pos.x,
      y: new_pos.y,
      z: new_pos.z,

      onComplete: () => {
        offset.x = controls.target.x - camera.position.x;
        offset.y = controls.target.y - camera.position.y;
        offset.z = controls.target.z - camera.position.z;

        camera_is_moving = false;
        controls.enabled = true;
      },
    });
    gsap.to(controls.target, {
      duration: camera_travel_duration,
      x: offset.x + new_pos.x,
      z: offset.z + new_pos.z,
    });
  };
```

I solves my problem completely but I still don't know why the previous code didn't work.